# How to pull rows from repeater table which contains value in select

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create a shortcode for custom posts I have on the WordPress site. Advanced custom fields plugin is used.

In the shortcode my itention is to pass car id, and bonus type. All cars have several bonuses in the table, but I want to pull just info from the row of bonus type. Either one or several bonus types could be applied.

[get_car_bonus carId="5,7,9,13" bonusType = "Welcome, 30-OFF"] [/get_car_bonus]

In the shortcode above, I pass 4 cars and I want to show  for every car rows from repeater where bonus types are WELCOME and 30-OFF.

Here is how repeater table looks:
[image: repeater table]

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is short code example based on your question (i've removed spaces between commas in bonus type and change attribute name to `bonusTypes`)...

`[get_car_bonus carId="5,7,9,13" bonusTypes="Welcome,30-OFF"] [/get_car_bonus]`

This is not tested but maybe this might get you on the right track, see comments in my php code below so you know what is happening...

```php
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function get_car_bonus_shortcode($atts) { 
  
    // store our passed shortcode attributes into var
    $atts = shortcode_atts([
        'carId' => false,
        'bonusTypes' => false
    ], $atts, 'get_car_bonus');

    // if either carId or bonusType is false return early
    if(!$atts['carId'] || !$atts['bonusTypes']) {
        return false;
    }

    // assuming your passed shortcode attribute values are correctly formatted comma serperated strings
    // lets explode them into arrays

    // explode car ids to integer array
    $cars = array_map('intval', explode(',', $atts['carId'));

    // explode bonus types to array
    $bonus_types = explode(',', $atts['bonusTypes');

    // now lets get our car posts from car ids (assuming your post type name is `cars`)
    $cars_query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'cars',
        'post__in' => $cars
    ]);

    // results data storage array
    $data = [];

    // if we have cars
    if($cars_query->have_posts() ) :

        // loop through each car found
        while ( $cars_query->have_posts() ) : $cars_query->the_post(); 

            // get repeater field rows in your car post
            $rows = get_field('your_repeater_field_name', $cars_query->post->ID, false);

            // if we have repeater rows
            if($rows) {

                // now lets loop through each repeater row
                foreach($rows as $row) {

                    // get repeater field bonus type select field value
                    // assuming your select field return type matches your passed shortcode bonus type strings
                    $bonus_type = $row['bonus_type'];

                    // if any of the passed attribute bonus types are equal to the current repeater field bonus type select field value
                    if(in_array($bonus_type, $bonus_types)) {

                        // now here is where we can store the current repeater row fields for matching bonus type to our data results array (by car id then bonus type)
                        $data[$cars_query->post->ID][$bonus_type] = [
                            'offer' => $row['offer'],
                            'bonus' => $row['bonus']
                        ];

                    }
                }

            }

        }

        endwhile;

    endif;

    // if we have result data added to data array 
    if($data) {

        // print result data (see end of answer of how example data is returned)
        return '<pre>' .  print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';

    }

    // return false 
    return false;
    
}

// register shortcode
add_shortcode('get_car_bonus', 'get_car_bonus_shortcode');
```

Your question is a little vague on how you want to handle the final output. But if you run this shortcode below...

`[get_car_bonus carId="5,7,9,13" bonusTypes="Welcome,30-OFF"] [/get_car_bonus]`

Example returned output...

```text
Array
(
    [5] => array
        (
            ['Welcome'] => array
                (
                    ['offer'] => 'Offer repeater field example text'
                    ['bonus'] => 'Bonus repeater field example text'
                )
            ['30-OFF'] => array
                (
                    ['offer'] => 'Offer repeater field example text'
                    ['bonus'] => 'Bonus repeater field example text'
                )
        )
    [7] => array
        (
            ['30-OFF'] => array
                (
                    ['offer'] => 'Offer repeater field example text'
                    ['bonus'] => 'Bonus repeater field example text'
                )
        )
    [9] => array
        (
            ['Welcome'] => array
                (
                    ['offer'] => 'Offer repeater field example text'
                    ['bonus'] => 'Bonus repeater field example text'
                )
        )
    [13] => array
        (
            ['Welcome'] => array
                (
                    ['offer'] => 'Offer repeater field example text'
                    ['bonus'] => 'Bonus repeater field example text'
                )
            ['30-OFF'] => array
                (
                    ['offer'] => 'Offer repeater field example text'
                    ['bonus'] => 'Bonus repeater field example text'
                )
        )
)
```

I'm guessing you want to use this data to perhaps loop offer information for passed car ids.

Good luck hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for helping. When I dump $bonus_type = $row['bonus_type']; I got null. It looks like repeaters meta_key are not bonus_type and they are dynamic

Comment: Yeah but whats the name of you repeater field, have you changed `your_repeater_field_name` to your repeater field name?

Comment: thank you. I changed it. But I had to add insted of offer I had to write field_60f940b9ad1fb. Not sure why? I managed to solve issues I had with your assistance.

Comment: Interesting, you can always dump `get_fields()` or `get_field_objects()` to see the  what field name is. Anyway glad you got it working.